# ubuntu 16.04 dual booting problem

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

I had installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a dell laptop which already had windows 10.
The problem was that on switching ON my laptop, grub won't show up with the list of OS to choose from.
Instead, it would start Ubuntu by default and I wanted grub to show windows option too.
So I tried the boot repair :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

and it was successful and I was asked to reboot my device which I did.

Now, when I switch ON the laptop, a message comes which goes like
'can't find grub ..missing file ... trying to go to rescue mode'
and nothing happens from there.
I cant either go to ubuntu or windows now. I have 'to manunally boot from windows bootloader on sartup to go windows which is annoying.
But, there seems to be no way I can go to ubuntu. Help,please!

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Always you install ubuntu dual boot with windows you must better deactivate secure boot. Yes, supergrub can reinstall your grub but I recommend you:

Rescue your files with an usb Ubuntu life session. Copy to another drive.

Inside windows - disc administrator - erase ubuntu partitions (Swap, \, Home, etc).

Deactivate secure boot by BIOS option. UEFI can be activated.

Install again ubuntu. Better you configure manually partitions. Swap (4Gb), \ (20Gb), and Home (Gb you want, at least 100Gb for your files). All three are essential.

Hope it helps you.